# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Tips' threw an exception

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7, static-constructor

I am trying to access the values of a static list. However when I try to do so this exception is thrown.

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Tips' threw an exception. --  -> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The class with the list.

```
    public static class Tips
{
    //private List<Tip> roadtips = new List<Tip>();
    public static List<Tip> tips { get; set; }

     static Tips()
    {
        tips.Add(new Tip("Don't use your mobile phone whilst driving", "Making or receiving a call, even using a 'hands free' phone, can distract your attention from driving and could lead to an accident. "));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Children", "Children often act impulsively, take extra care outside schools, near buses and ice cream vans when they might be around."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Take a break", "Tiredness is thought to be a major factor in more than 10% of road accidents. Plan to stop for at least a 15 minute break every 2 hours on a long journey."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Don't drink and drive", "Any alcohol, even a small amount , can impair your driving so be a safe driver don't drive and drive."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Anticipate ", "Observe and anticipate other road users and use your mirrors regularly."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Use car seats ", "Child and baby seats should be fitted properly and checked every trip."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Keep your distance ", "Always keep a two second gap between you and the car in front."));
    }
}
```

This is class trying to access the list.

```
 public partial class tip : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public tip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random r = new Random();
        int rInt = r.Next(0, 6); 
        tipname.Text = Tips.tips[rInt].Name;
        tipdesc.Text = Tips.tips[rInt].Description;
    }
}
```

What's causing this to occur? Is there a better way to store these tips. I just need a list of tips to output to two textblocks on a Windows phone page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like you ever initialize the auto-implemented property `tips` to a value.  Hence it is `null` and causing an exception in your static initializer.  Try initializing the value

```
static Tips()
{
  tips = new List<Tip>();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

tips hasn't been initialized.

You need to new it.

```
 static Tips()
 {
    tips = new List<Tip>();
    tips.Add(new Tip("Don't use your mobile phone whilst driving", "Making or receiving 
    ...  
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure “new” is a verb? :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class Tips
{
    //private List<Tip> roadtips = new List<Tip>();
    public static List<Tip> tips { get; set; }

    static Tips()
    {
        tips = new List<Tip>(); 
        tips.Add(new Tip("Don't use your mobile phone whilst driving", "Making or receiving a call, even using a 'hands free' phone, can distract your attention from driving and could lead to an accident. "));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Children", "Children often act impulsively, take extra care outside schools, near buses and ice cream vans when they might be around."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Take a break", "Tiredness is thought to be a major factor in more than 10% of road accidents. Plan to stop for at least a 15 minute break every 2 hours on a long journey."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Don't drink and drive", "Any alcohol, even a small amount , can impair your driving so be a safe driver don't drive and drive."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Anticipate ", "Observe and anticipate other road users and use your mirrors regularly."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Use car seats ", "Child and baby seats should be fitted properly and checked every trip."));
        tips.Add(new Tip("Keep your distance ", "Always keep a two second gap between you and the car in front."));
    }
}
```